# NSOpenPanel in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am trying to follow [apples XMLParsing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html) for the iphone SDK, but getting in a right muddle around this NSOpenPanel. It appears to be in the mac os framework, but how can i use it as it suggests int he dev centre for the iphone? Any suggestion welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available on the iOS Platform. And there's no dialog to select files on iOS devices.

```
Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.
```

You can open files like this:

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir, user.picture];
UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:jpegFilePath];
```